# React Native Bottom Tab Navigator - Icons not displaying

Tags: react-native

```
/* eslint-disable react-native/no-inline-styles */
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
import * as React from 'react';

import Home from '../screens/home';
import Review from '../screens/reviewDetails';
import Profile from '../screens/profile';
import Settings from '../screens/settings';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import { COLORS, icons } from '../constants';
import { Image } from 'react-native';

import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';

import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

export default function HomeStack() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Home',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Review Details" component={Review} options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Review',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

my code for a bottom tab navigator runs without any errors however when run in the emmulator the icons on the navigator do not display they are replaced by a crossed box? the tab navigator is also contained within a drawer content navigator which is in turn the child of a root stack navigator. all dependencies have been installed yet the error persists

Comment: Does doing it with Ionicons (which you have imported) work?

Comment: nope ive tried with both

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reading the documentation of the `Tab.Navigator`, you should define the icons inside of that. It would look like this:

```js
<Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
            let iconName;

            if (route.name === 'Home') {
              iconName = focused
                ? 'ios-information-circle'
                : 'ios-information-circle-outline';
            } else if (route.name === 'Settings') {
              iconName = focused ? 'ios-list-box' : 'ios-list';
            }

            // You can return any component that you like here!
            return <MaterialCommunityIcons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
          },
        })}
        tabBarOptions={{
          activeTintColor: 'tomato',
          inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
        }}
      >
  <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
  <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

This means you would be changing the component based on the route name. The reason behind it is that `Tab.Screen` should have information about the screen that will be displayed, while `Tab.Navigator` should handle the navigator (bottom strip with tabs) part of navigation.

Comment: nope - with this code a completely blank screen loadsd

Comment: return icon works for me...

Answer (score 4):

Crossed box on android might come when the **react-native-vector-icons** is not link properly.

run this command

```
react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

and in android/app/build.gradle file add this.

```
project.ext.vectoricons = [
    iconFontNames: [ 'MaterialIcons.ttf' ] // Name of the font files you want to copy
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

I hope this will fix your crossed box issue.

Comment: Thank you I will give it a try when I am free and let you know

Comment: thankyou the link cli command works - thankyou for the adivce

Answer (score 2):

return statement is missing in your code.
You can do it like this:

```
<Tab.Screen name="Review Details" component={Review} options={{
      tabBarLabel: 'Review',
      tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
        return <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={26} />
      ),
    }} />
```

So update this line,

```
<MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={26} />
```

to this

```
return <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={26} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the `setting.gradle` and add the following line:

```
include ':react-native-svg'
project(':react-native-svg').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-svg/android')
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
includeBuild('../node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin')
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':app'
if (settings.hasProperty("newArchEnabled") && settings.newArchEnabled == "true") {
    include(":ReactAndroid")
    project(":ReactAndroid").projectDir = file('../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid')
}
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize your post. The edits applied here are valid formatting efforts.